# Multiple filtered lists per NSArrayController

Tags: cocoa, nsmutablearray, cocoa-bindings, nsarraycontroller

What I need to do is simple, Say I have a list of student domain objects

```
@implementation Student : CPObject
{
    CPString name @accessors;
    BOOL isLate @accessors;
    BOOL isMale @accessors:
}
```

I have a list of these `Student` objects stored in an `NSMutableArray` which is a part of my model object.

I have a `NSTableView` showing these `Student` objects, the table has check boxes to edit the `isLate` and `isMale` attribute. The table is backed by an `NSArrayController` which proxys the `NSMutableArray` from the model.

Else where in the interface, I want to have 2 textfields displaying the "number of late students" and "number of male students" and thats where my problem comes in.

Since `NSArrayController` supports filtering via predicate, my initial thought was to create 3 `NSArrayController` objects, one for proxying the tableview, on for each aggregate display (number of late students, number of male students). For the aggregate controllers, I would apply filtering and bind the text fields to the `arrangedObjects.@count`. However this seems like the wrong approach since the main controller making edits to the `NSMutableArray` would have no way of informing the changes made to the 2 other controllers.

Another approach I thought about was mentioned here. http://cocoa-nut.de/?tag=nsarraycontroller. Using this approach, I would binding the 2 "slave" `NSArrayController` performing the aggregate operations on the "master" controller which backs the tableview. However this approach doesn't seem that clean either.

Thirdly, I read this post here: [Singleton NSMutableArray accessed by NSArrayController in multiple NIB's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3113974/singleton-nsmutablearray-accessed-by-nsarraycontroller-in-multiple-nibs) . This tends to suggest that I should move the complexity into my model object instead. Perhaps I should create a `StudentList` class with `allStudents`, `maleStudents`, `lateStudents` attributes for binding? This seems overkill for something so simple.

Overall, this seems like a pretty common and simple operation to have in a program but I'm relatively new to Cocoa so I am really not sure what is the "right" way to do it. Please enlighten me.

Comment: My instinct would be that the third approach is the best - if you encapsulate the complexities of your model then it will be easier to maintain it.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I agree that having "fat models" are always better than "fat controllers". In this case it feels somewhat wrong for me to move the logic into the model. This is because the 2 aggregate functions are purely view-related logic and is not used anywhere else. In a typical "MVP" architecture, It seems like sticking this logic into the presentation model would be the best approach rather than polluting my domain model. In the case of cocoa, since controllers also acts as the view-mediator, I was wondering perhaps that would be the right place to put it.